# React testing using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component with the below render method

```
render() {
    var id=this.props.itemid
    var maxquantity = this.props.maxquantity
    return(

        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.name}</td>
            <td><img width="50px" height="50px" src={this.props.img} /></td>
            <td> {this.props.price}</td>
            <td><input id="quantity" type="number" value={this.state.quant} ref="quantity" onChange = {()=> this.handleQuantityChange(maxquantity,this.props.name)}/></td>
            <td><button type="button" onClick={() => this.addItem(id,this.props.price)}>Add</button></td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

`onChange` of the quantity input, `this.handleQuantityChange()` method is called and the method is as shown below

```
handleQuantityChange(maxquantity,name) {

    const newQuantity = parseInt(this.refs.quantity.value)

    if(newQuantity > parseInt(maxquantity)) {
        var message="You cannot buy more than " +maxquantity+" "+name
        this.setState({errorMessage:"You cannot buy more than " +maxquantity+" "+name})
    }

    this.setState({quant:newQuantity})
    this.props.quantityChange(message)
}
```

The value of quant state is changed to the ref value

I wrote a test case as shown below

```
describe('quantity input', () => {
it('should respond to the change event and change the state of Item component', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow (<Item/>);
    const input = wrapper.find('#quantity')
    console.log(input)
    input.simulate('change', {target: {value:3}});
    expect(wrapper.state('quant')).toEqual(3);
    });     
});
```

but it throws an error saying

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

for `this.refs.quantity.value`

what should be my test case. please help

Answer (score 0):

Shallow rendering doesn't work with refs.

If you're using Enzyme, you could use [`mount`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/mount.html) instead of [`shallow`](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/shallow.html) and this should solve your issues.

Cheers